# Pushing Distinct Values to Array and Finding New Length

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

Trying to sort and push only the distinct values into a new array and then find the length of the resulting array. See code below. The UniqueTeams.length is coming out to be 1, when it should be 5 (I thought).

```
 var teams = [[formSS.getRange("F8").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("F10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("F12").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("F14").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("F16").getValue()]];

var uniqueTeams = removeDups(teams);
if(uniqueTeams.length < 5){
  {SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(uniqueTeams);
      return;}
}

function removeDups(array) {
  var outArray = [];
  array.sort();
  outArray.push(array[0]);
  for(var n in array){
    if(outArray[outArray.length-1]!=array[n]){
      outArray.push(array[n]);
    }
  }
  return outArray;
}


uniqueTeams = Alabama (2),Maryland (10),Cleveland St (15),BYU (6),Liberty (13)
uniqueTeams.length = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Get unique elements

```
function remdup() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const t = sh.getRange('F8:F16').getValues().flat();
  let teams = [t[0], t[2], t[4], t[6], t[8]];
  let s = new Set(teams)
  teams = [...s];
  Logger.log(teams.join(','))
}
```

[Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Answer (score 0):

Cooper's answer it the best ultimate solution. But if you want just to fix your code you can try to change the line:

```
var uniqueTeams = removeDups(teams);
```

with:

```
var uniqueTeams = removeDups(teams[0]);
```

Since the `teams` is a 2D array [[...]].